# How to find the java window dialog that is dependent on its parent for closing

Tags: java, swing, dialog

```
public class Settings extends JDialog
{
    public Settings()
    {
        setSize(200,200);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to find the java window dialog that is dependent on its parent for closing. A typical window that goes "bang" when you try to access its parent window without first satisfied it. I'll appreciate your input.

Comment: Are you referring to a modal dialog?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for Window.getOwner() or Window.getOwnedWindows();

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for setModal(true);

Comment: example would be nice.